# Google DLP - Displaying the Region using InfoTypes.list()

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-dlp

After integrating the Google DLP API, the ListInfoTypes() currently returns the name, description, supported types of the infotypes present in the infotypes reference. Is it possible to also obtain the region for the infotypes like "Australia" or "Argentina" as a seperate field?

Currently this is my output:

```
  "name": "AUSTRALIA_MEDICARE_NUMBER",
      "displayName": "Australia medicare number",
      "supportedBy": [
        "INSPECT"
      ],
      "description": "A 9-digit Australian Medicare account
```

I need the Region as well for example Region: "Australia" for every other infotypes.

I also got around to see `locations.infoTypes.list()` but I'm not sure which location I should enter in the filter to get any value.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the REST API there doesn't appear to be identifying data that can be formally used to determine the region.  If we look at the InfoTypeDescription JSON structure found here:

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ListInfoTypesResponse#InfoTypeDescription

we see that "name" is described as an "internal name of the InfoType".  I wondered if we could depend on a structure of the string ... perhaps `(.)*_.*` as a regular expression grouping.  While this might work, it shouldn't be relied upon without investigation of more samples and the docs don't describe the structure.

If you really need a solution, my recommendation would be to dump ALL the InfoTypes and then manually group the "name" fields into the regions of interest to you.  You could then store this as CSV or JSON and have a reference piece of data that you could use in your app and regenerate as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great feature request I'll forward to the team. In the short term you can hack the name as ones that are regional will say they are in their name.